# Script executes mysql query and returns column name + result

Tags: mysql, linux, wordpress, bash

I'm scripting a little tool that I troubleshoot wordpress sites with.

This script has a function called wpsql which I pass SQL queries into. Then, it calls another function called `wpdb_creds`. wpdb_creds echos 5 variables parsed from `wp-config.php`; the database host, name, username, and password, in that order. wpsql catches these variables and stores them in a local variable as a string. the local variable is then split into an array and stored in another variable using IFS. Then i execute the query by using the mysql command, giving it the database credentials and the query. The output from this is echo'd.

However, the problem I'm having is, the script will return the column name as well as the output from the query. For example, when I execute a query such as (ignore `%table_prefix%`, it gets replaced with the database table prefix in `wp-config.php` using sed in wpsql):

```
SELECT option_value FROM %table_prefix%options WHERE option_name='active_plugins';
```

The output I get is:

```
option_value a:5:{i:0;s:29:"gravityforms/gravityforms.php";i:1;s:45:"no-captcha-recaptcha/no-captcha-recaptcha.php";i:2;s:25:"relevanssi/relevanssi.php";i:3;s:41:"woot-search-engine/woot-search-engine.php";i:4;s:23:"wordfence/wordfence.php";}
```

`option_value` shouldn't be returned in the output and I can't figure out why it's doing so. Here are the functions involved:

```
function wp_domain_root {
    found=false;local root='';cwd=${PWD} 
    IFS="/" read -a dirs <<< "$cwd"
    for((i="${#dirs[@]}"; i>0; i--)); do 
        tmp_dir=""
        for((ii=0;ii < $i; ii++)); do 
            tmp_dir+="${dirs[ $ii ]}/"
        done

        if [ -f $tmp_dir"/wp-config.php" ]; then root=$tmp_dir; break; fi
    done

    echo $root
}

function wpdb_creds {
    local domain_root=$(wp_domain_root)

    if [[ ${#domain_root} -ge 5 ]]; then
        read -r dbhost dbname dbpass dbuser dbprefix <<< $(cat $domain_root"wp-config.php" | egrep "^[^/].*[\"']DB_(NAME|USER|PASSWORD|HOST[^_])|table_prefix" | sort -d | sed "s/.*[\"']\(.*\)[\"'].*;.*/\1/" )

        if [[ ! -z $1 && $1 == '-p' ]]; then 
            echo -e "\nWP Database Info\n\tHostname: "$dbhost"\n\tDatabase: "$dbname"\n\tPassword: "$dbpass"\n\tUsername: "$dbuser"\n\tPrefix:   "$dbprefix"\n";
        else
            local dbcreds=($dbhost $dbname $dbpass $dbuser $dbprefix)
            echo "${dbcreds[@]}"
    fi; else echo -e 'Could not find a wp-config.php file...'; fi
}

function wp_sql {
    args=$@
    local query=$(IFS=" "; echo "${args[*]}")

    if [[ ! -z $1 ]]; then 
    local dbcredstr=$(wpdb_creds)

    IFS=" " read -a dbcreds <<< "$dbcredstr"
        if [ "${#dbcreds[@]}" -eq 5 ]; then
            sql_query=$(echo $query | sed "s/%table_prefix%/${dbcreds[4]}/g")
            echo $(mysql -u "${dbcreds[3]}" -p"${dbcreds[2]}" -h "${dbcreds[0]}" -D "${dbcreds[1]}" -e "$sql_query"  2>&1)
        fi
    fi
}

function wpplug_print_active {
    echo $(wp_sql "SELECT option_value FROM %table_prefix%options WHERE option_name='active_plugins';");
}
```

Comment: most db systems have a command that turns off displaying the column header, (and footers, and other non-data ). Check the documentation for the `mysql command-line`.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! That was indeed the problem. Specifying -N or --skip-column-names solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing -N or --skip-column-names to the mysql command solved the problem.